# Why doesn't my variable value get updated? thank you for your help, I havent coded in a while and I did not know about what you were saying so thanks

Tags: python

this is the code

```
import random

bank = 0

for i in range(100000):
    gamble = int(input())
    win = random.randint(1, 2)
    if win == 1 :
        print("lose")
        bank - gamble
    else:
        print("win")
        bank + gamble
    print(bank)
```

can someone please help me, I am not close to a pythoneer and am just a beginner level coder, so I would like to get some help and explanation  on why it didn't work

Comment: You're not updating the variable bank.  To increase: `bank = bank + gamble` or more succintly: `bank += gamble`.  Similarly to reduce: `bank = bank - gamble` or `bank -= gamble`.

Answer (score 2):

You are subtracting two numbers, but then, you do nothing with the result - what do you expect ? As in real life, subtracting a number from another does not change one of them. Same is the case when you add, divide, multiply, … two numbers. You either have to save the result of the mathematical operation by assigning it to a variable:

```py
    if win == 1 :
        print("lose")
        bank = bank - gamble
    else:
        print("win")
        bank = bank + gamble
```

or do the mathematical operation in place, by putting an equal sign after the operator:

```py
    if win == 1 :
        print("lose")
        bank -= gamble
    else:
        print("win")
        bank += gamble
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bank - gamble
bank + gamble
```

Those two expressions do not store side-effect you need to create assignment expression.
Try this:

```
bank -= gamble
bank += gamble
```

Or:

```
bank = bank - gamble
bank = bank + gamble
```